# Use Fubini's Theorem to verify the integration by parts formula, and justify that the hypotheses of Fubini's Theorem are satisfied.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ and $g$ be Lebesgue integrable real-valued functions on $[0,1]$, and define

$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt, \quad \text{and} \quad G(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt.$$

Use Fubini's Theorem to verify the integration by parts formula

$$\int_0^1 F(x)g(x)dx = F(1)G(1) - \int_0^1 f(x)G(x)dx.$$

Justify that the hypotheses of Fubini's Theorem are satisfied.

This one seems straightforward to us, but for some reason we can't get anything nice to appear.

Here are our attempts for the left-hand side and the right-hand side respectively after the hint:

$$\begin{aligned} \int_0^1 F(x)g(x)dx &= \int_0^1 \int_0^x f(t)dtg(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 1_{[0,x]}f(t)g(x)dtdx\\
&= \int_0^1 f(t) \int_0^1 1_{[0,x]}g(x)dxdt. \end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned} F(1)G(1) - \int_0^1 f(x)G(x)dx &= F(1)G(1) - \int_0^1 f(x)\int_0^x g(t)dtdx\\
&= F(1)G(1) - \int_0^1\int_0^1 1_{[0,x]}f(x)g(t)dtdx\\
&= F(1)G(1) - \int_0^1g(t)\int_0^1 1_{[0,x]}f(x)dxdt.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: use Fubini is a good hint, that is, substitute the definition of $F$ and $G$ in all places and see what happen

Comment: We proceed in that way, but we cannot seem to get the two sides to equal each other. @Masacroso

Comment: show what you did, using Fubini's the result is immediate

Comment: I edited the post to include our calculations. @Masacroso

Comment: The integral $\int_0^x \int_0^1 f(t) g(x) dx dt$ does not make sense. You can't use x as an integration boundary in the outer integral when x only appears in the inner integral. Hint: Rewrite $\int_0^x f(t) dt = \int_0^1 1_{t\leq x} f(t) dt$ and then apply Fubini.

Comment: I recalculated according to your hint I think @PhoemueX. Apologies, but I don't really see what else to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first few steps just involves rewriting the terms as they are defined and moving constants inside or outside of an integral as needed.
$$
\begin{align*}F(1)G(1)&=\Big(\int_0^1f(t)dt\Big)\Big(\int_0^1 g(x)dx\Big)= \int_0^1g(x)\Big(\int_0^1 f(t)dt\Big)dx\\
&= \int_0^1g(x)\Big(\int_0^x f(t)dt\Big)dx + \int_0^1g(x)\Big(\int_x^1 f(t)dt\Big)dx\\
&= \int_0^1 g(x)F(x)dx + \int_0^1g(x)\Big(\int_x^1 f(t)dt\Big)dx\end{align*}$$
Now we use Fubini's Theorem to show that the second integral takes the appropriate form. Well
$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1 g(x)\Big(\int_x^1 f(t)dt\Big)dx &= \int_0^1g(x)\int_0^1 1_{[0\leq x\leq t\leq 1]}(x,t)f(t)dt dx\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 1_{[0\leq x\leq t\leq 1]}(x,t)g(x)f(t)dt dx\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1 1_{[0\leq x\leq t\leq 1]}(x,t)g(x)f(t)dxdt\\
&= \int_0^1f(t)\int_0^1 1_{[0\leq x\leq t\leq 1]}(x,t)g(x)dx dt \\ 
&= \int_0^1f(t)\Big(\int_0^1 1_{[0\leq x\leq t]}(x)g(x)dx\Big) dt \\ 
&= \int_0^1f(t)\Big(\int_0^t g(x)dx\Big) dt \\ 
&= \int_0^1 f(t)G(t)dt\end{align*}$$
Hence after a change of variables we have that
$$F(1)G(1) = \int_0^1 g(x)F(x)dx + \int_0^1 f(x)G(x)dx $$

Answer (score -3):

$$f(x)=u(x)v(x)$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}v+\frac{dv}{dx}u$$
$$df=v.du+u.dv$$
$$\int df=\int v.du+\int u.dv$$
$$\int u.dv=f-\int v.du$$
$$\int u.dv=uv-\int v.du$$
If you don't have to use Fubini's theorem